# Let EditText be written in only specific word

Tags: android, regex, android-edittext, android-input-filter

How could you restrict `EditText` anything except one predefined word?

Let say input should be exactly word "Hello" (ignore case). Therefore letters would be ignored except letters from "hello" in respected order.

I don't really want to use `TextWatcher` and check manually char at position. I'm wondering how could do that using `InputFilter` and `Regex`?

What I tried:

```
    InputFilter onboardingFilter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            String checkMe = String.valueOf(source.charAt(i));

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("hello", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(checkMe);
            boolean valid = matcher.matches();
            if(!valid){
                return "";
            } 
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

This doesn't let me to input anything. I belive the problem is within regex.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're running the regex for 'hello' on each individual character (in this case, h, e, l, l, o, individually). But, it will never make it passed h, because the regex 'hello' will not be found for the character 'h'.

Secondly, you're never returning the actual String that has been input by the user, so it will always be an empty String.

Third, since we know the expected pattern but not the input, you could actually reverse it and use the input as the pattern to search within the target pattern and use the regex starts-with (^) to ensure ordering.

Try something like this:

```
private String last = "";

InputFilter onboardingFilter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        String sourceAsRegex = "^" + source;
        String desiredInput = "hello";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sourceAsRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(desiredInput);

        if(matcher.find())
            last = source;

        return last;
    }
};
```

Comment: last has to be a member of the class that surrounds the instance of your InputFilter. It gets set to the current source any time matcher.matches() returns true, so as you go through, the sourceAsRegex and last values, respectively, become (from initial state): "^", "" >> "^h", "h" >> "^he", "he" >> etc. Now let's say I put a p in there, "^hep" would fail searching within "hello" and would not set last, so it would remain at "he" and the input field should remain unchanged

Comment: Try replacing matcher.matches() with matcher.find() and I think it should work.